# Java recursion-finding the minimal number index in array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am learning recursions in java, but I am having troubles with finding index of the minimal element in array.. So I'll need some help.. And if you have some good explanation of recursions please leave a comment.

Comment: Post a code snippet of your attempt at it, then we can help you from there.

Comment: On SO people are required to show "some research effort"... Show what you have tried, what failed, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than posting an answer to your question I'll provide a general template for recursion. You should then have an attempt and come back when you have a specific question.

In general a recursive method follow the following form:

```
private Result recursiveMethod(Context current) {
    if (current.isInSimpleFormWithObviousAnswer()) {
        return new Result(current.getValue());
    } else {
        Result result = new Result(current.getValue());
        for (Context reducedContext: current.possibleReducedContexts()) {
            result = result.possiblyCombine(recursiveMethod(reducedContext)));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is a general form. In many cases you don't need `Result` and `Context` classes as you will be using some primitive type or a collection. There are also many situations in which the recursive call is not an iteration as there is only one possible 'reduced context'. Both of these are true in your situation.

Comment: Perhaps `result = result.possibleCombine(...)` to allow inheritance in the `Result` class :).

Comment: @CommuSoft good suggestion. Will add that

Answer (score 0):

As with most recursive algorithms on arrays, you have:

- **a base case** where the length of the (remaining) array is zero; and
- **an iterative case**: where the problem for an array of length *n* is resolve partly by solving it for an array with length *n-1* or *n/2*; or another way to subdivide it.

Let's talk about the divide-an-conquer way: *n/2*. First we will attach an index range to the array. These indices specify where in the array we start and end looking. This is more efficient than effectively copying (parts of) an array into another array:

```
public static int minimum (int[] values) {
    return minimum(values,0,values.length);
}
```

Where the called `minimum` will be the recursive function.

Now for the recursive function there are two cases:

- in the case the length of the array is one, simply return that element (1); or
- in case the array has more elements, subdivide it into two subarrays of approximately equal length, calculate their minima, and return the minimum of the two (2).

Or in code:

```
public static int minimum (int[] value, int frm, int to) {
    if(to-frm <= 1) {//(1)
        return value[frm];
    } else {         //(2)
        int mid = (frm+to)/2;
        int m1 = minimum(value,frm,mid);
        int m2 = minimum(value,mid,to);
        return Math.min(m1,m2);
    }
}
```

[**jDoodle demo**](//jdoodle.com/a/so)

**TODO:** Now you only need to translate this to let it work with *returning the index* of the smallest element instead of the element itself.

Comment: I think you might have just done OP's homework ;-)

Comment: @sprinter: the question seems to suggest to return the *index*, so if the OP can manage to translate this to work with indices, I think he/she understands it ;).